# Why does this IF FOUND have a condition that is always true?

Tags: visual-foxpro

FoxPro7

Note: The word "record set" is probably not correct but I really don't understand how they work. I'm a SQL guy so I'm trying to translate. Is it a view? Is it a copy of the data? I have no idea.

Questions:

1. If you are using the 2 record set and make a change does the change show up in the 1 record set? Maybe they both point at the same record set?
2. How could the IF FOUND ever be false? The code compares a subset of a table to the full table. It should always be true.
3. Is the DO WHILE affected by SKIP? It's hard to tell if the record set is fixed once you start a DO WHILE or if you can mess with the records in the loop along the way. I'm not grasping the difference between "where you are" in a loop of records and "what you are pointing at" if you change the row.

Thank you!

```
    Select 1
    Use tblincls    
    
    Select 2
    Use tblincls Again
    Set Filter To CLASS_CODE = '5156'
    Goto Top

    Do While Not Eof()
    
    nagency_code = agency_code
    nindex_no = index_no
    nclass_code = CLASS_CODE
    npys_exp = pys_exp
    namt_exp = amt_exp

    Select 1
    Seek nagency_code + nindex_no + nclass_code
    If Found()
        Replace pys_exp With (pys_exp + npys_exp)
        Select 2
    Else
        Select 2
        Replace CLASS_CODE With '5157'
    Endif
    Select 2
    Skip
    Enddo

    Close Tables All
    Use tblincls Excl
    Delete All For CLASS_CODE = '5156'
    Pack
    Close Tables All
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Note: The word "record set" is probably not correct but I really don't
> understand how they work. I'm a SQL guy so I'm trying to translate. Is
> it a view? Is it a copy of the data? I have no idea.

Based on the code sample, the "record set" is most likely a VFP table (but could be a view) that is part of a VFP database container (dbc). The reason I know this is there is one fieldname that exceeds 10 characters: a free table can only have 10 characters; exceeding 10 characters would require the table/view to be in a dbc. I will answer your questions using "table".

Answers:

1. The tblincls table is opened twice. Any change made to the table will be reflected in both select areas (1 and 2). Think of it like 2 users opening one shared file. Both are working on the same data file.
2. FOUND() will never be false if there is data in the filtered table (Select 2). It won't necessarily *always* be true because there is a possibility that there will not be data in the filtered file in which case, the "If Found()" code doesn't get called.
3. The DO WHILE is affected by SKIP: the filtered table (Select 2) is moved forward 1 record each loop. For example, if #1 has 20 total records and #2 (filtered) has 4 records, the code you have posted loops through #2 (1st, 2nd, 3rd, 4th). variables are created for each of the 4 records in #2 and updates are made in #1 by finding (SEEK()) the record in #1.

Having explained all that, it looks as though all the updates made to the table are completely wiped out at the end by deleting all the records (CLASS_CODE='5156') and packing them. CLASS_CODE will never be set to '5157' based on this snippet. It doesn't make sense. This is poorly written. All it seems to do is delete records where CLASS_CODE='5156'.

Comment: Thank you very much Mr Ed for all of your insight. I learned a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Ed already explained it quite well IMHO. Let me add\expand more:

1. Record set is a broad term, it might mean anything that is a set of records (be it a table, view, table valued function, cursor ...) - just like in SQL in general.

Select 1 and select 2 mean, select "work area" 1 and 2. You might think those numbers as unique connection handles. You can open the same table\view (or cursor...) in multiple work areas using the keyword "AGAIN". The first one uses the same alias as the table name (let's say table - and very likely it is a table). Second one is at the mercy of VFP and assigned an automatic alias. Aliases are just local aliases in the SQL.

And yes, they are 2 connections pointing to the same table.

2. You might be perfectly right on that. However, with the existing code, it wouldn't even work and cause an error. If you really have this code and it is running, then there is some preceding code, that silences the errors. What really happens there with this code is:

It errors on SEEK ... line
Error is silenced with some preceding code I believe
Due to silencing, FOUND() is always FALSE, current filtered data is replaced with '5157' and skips to next record.

If SEEK wouldn't error, still a match is not guaranteed and FOUND() might be false, because:
SEEK operates on current index. Current index may not be one that matches a search on:

```
agency_code + index_no + class_code
```

WORSE, the data types are not known in this code, those variables are prefixed with 'n' all, which might mean they are numerics, then that would be a summing of 3 numeric fields, versus concatenation of 3 character fields. ie:

agency_code = 1
index_no = 1
class_code = 1

and that seek would then mean:

SEEK 3

However, we already know CLASS_CODE is a string, others also should be string (or it is another error).

3. Do While cares only about its logical expression part. In this code it is only checking if it is EOF(). And EOF() means, End Of File "of current table\view\cursor". Since just hitting before to ENDDO it is doing a SELECT 2, that means the loop would continue until EOF is hit in work area 2 (filtered by CLASS_CODE='5156'). Since there is nothing else in code that moves the pointer in any tables, it is one pass of the records in work area 2 (in terms of SQL server, you declare a cursor for select with CLASS_CODE = '5156', fetch next until status not 0).

Let's expand commenting on the code itself:

```
* Select workarea 1 - like opening a new connection tab in SSMS to the same database
Select 1
* Open table tblincls in this work area
* it is like allocating a cursor but let's don't make it complex
Use tblincls


* Select workarea 2 - like opening a new connection tab in SSMS to the same database
Select 2
* Open table tblincls in this work area AGAIN with a local alias of (likely  - automatic) B
Use tblincls Again
* Filter this one 
Set Filter To CLASS_CODE = '5156'
Goto Top


* So up to this point it is as if you have 2 cursors allocated
* one with
* Select * from tblincls
* and the other
* Select * from tblincls where CLASS_CODE = '5156'


* Starting a loop using - on work area 2
Do While Not Eof()

* Copy contents of some fields to some memory vairables 
* (The variables on left are all memory variables,
* because in VFP you cannot do assigment to field variables)

    nagency_code = agency_code
    nindex_no = index_no
    nclass_code = CLASS_CODE
    npys_exp = pys_exp
    namt_exp = amt_exp

* Select work area 1
    Select 1
* Call SEEK. Since there is no index set, this would cause an error
* error is likely silenced by some preceding code (or in a TRY block)
* ie: If you had a line like this, code would continue without displaying any error 
* On error x=1 
* A dummy error silencer

    Seek nagency_code + nindex_no + nclass_code

* Always FALSE because of the error

* If index was set and error didn't occur
* and also index expression matches to 
* agency_code + index_no + class_code
* at least, then that would mean always TRUE
* It would find the record itself, or some other row
* Which row it would be is unpredictable (unless that expression is unique)

    If Found()
        Replace pys_exp With (pys_exp + npys_exp)
        Select 2
    Else
        Select 2
        Replace CLASS_CODE With '5157'
    EndIf
    
* Select work area 2 regardless of the above    
    Select 2
* Move the pointer
    Skip
Enddo

* No need to explain rest I guess
Close Tables All
Use tblincls Excl
Delete All For CLASS_CODE = '5156'
Pack
Close Tables All
```

The bottom line is, this is one of the worst codes I have ever seen. Probably I could translate it to SQL (saying SQL it might be any dialect):

```
Update tblincls Set Class_Code = '5157' where class_code = '5156'
```

like this, because what that code boils down to is this (and I would write that like that in VFP too).

Comment: Cetin thank you very much for all of the additional information. Your additional information helped clarify the whole code block and will assist me in ripping it apart more effectively.